# Static website served with single server-side variable

Tags: html, web-applications

I have a static website made with html, JS and CSS. However, I'd like to keep 1 or 2 stats about the users currently on the site and display it to everyone.

I thought about using a database but it seems like overkill for just 2 variables. I can't use LocalStorage because I don't want to rely on the clients to keep the data and also, I want to accumulate the data from all the users.

Any recommendations for a light-weight solution?

---

As a concrete example say I want to display the number of times all users have clicked a button. Every time someone clicks the button I want to update a variable on my server (or wherever) and display that new count to everyone on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *need* a server running a program for this.
Think about it like this: Right now your server is static, in an ever lasting, unchanging state. What you are asking for is a *change* that is reflected across all users. So you need a central place that has a state that *changes* - i.e. a running program. You won't get around this.

If you don't care about bots and authentication, a small [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in Python might be enough. If you prefer js. look into [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) which is also rather easy to setup. Another solution is [Google Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/), which would have the advantage that you don't have to setup a server yourself (and it's also very simple to get into).